# React form submission form.getData not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the submitted form data from a react-router-dom Form.

Below is my route (snippet from index.tsx):

```
import { ActionQuickConnect } from "./actions/ActionQuickConnect"

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Layout />,
        children: [
            {
                path: "quick-connect",
                element: <QuickConnect />,
                action: ActionQuickConnect
            }
        ],
    },
]);
```

Here's my ActionQuickConnect:

```
    export const ActionQuickConnect = async ({ request }) => {
        try {
            const data = await request.formData();
            console.log(data.getData('username'))
            //!! This output: data.getData is not a function
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    }
```

Component:

```
import { Form } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from "react";

    export const QuickConnect:React.FC = () => {
    <Form className="space-y-6" method="post" action="/quick-connect">
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text"/>
    </Form
    }
```

Can someone see what the problem might be?
createBrowserRouter should be a part of data api (as far as I can see)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering in your React application with `react-router-dom` is related to how you're trying to access form data in your `ActionQuickConnect` function. The `formData()` function returns a `FormData` object, but `getData` is not a method of the `FormData` interface. Instead, you should use the `get` method to retrieve the value of a specific form field.

Here's how you can modify your `ActionQuickConnect` function:

```js
export const ActionQuickConnect = async ({ request }) => {
    try {
        const data = await request.formData();
        console.log(data.get('username')); // Use the get method instead of getData
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
};
```

In this corrected version, `data.get('username')` is used to retrieve the value associated with the 'username' field from the form data. The `get` method is the correct way to access values in a `FormData` object.

Additionally, ensure that your form component is correctly structured and closed. In your `QuickConnect` component, the `<Form>` tag is not properly closed. Here's the corrected version:

```js
import { Form } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from "react";

export const QuickConnect: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <Form className="space-y-6" method="post" action="/quick-connect">
            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
        </Form>
    );
};
```

Make sure to include the `return` statement and properly close the `<Form>` tag. This will ensure that your form is rendered correctly and can submit data as expected.

Comment: It was that simple (usage of data.get instead of getData). Thank you so much for your clarification. Will accept when stackoverflow let me. Best

Answer (score 1):

Well, most likely is that there is no function .getData() in data variable.
Do this and see what you get:

```
console.log(data);
```